# What trailer means in kernel hacking slang?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Reading though the raspberry documentation. I found these text

"Note that DT and ATAGs are mutually exclusive. As a result, passing a DT blob to a kernel that doesn't understand it causes a boot failure. To guard against this, the loader checks kernel images for DT-compatibility, which is marked by a **trailer** added by the mkknlimg utility; this can be found here, or in the scripts directory of a recent kernel source tree. Any kernel without a trailer is assumed to be non-DT-capable."

at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md

and I am curious what does trailer means in kernel hacking slang?

I do **NOT** ask this question Raspberry Pi specifcly. I am intrested in a general explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trailer in this case is a few bytes appended to the end of an image during the build process. Loader at start up time can then look at few bytes at the end and if it finds magical value there (actual magic is 'RPTL' in your case). The loader then assumes DT-compatible kernel.

https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/blob/master/mkimage/mkknlimg#L21

Have a look here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/blob/master/mkimage/mkknlimg#L123 to find how and what is appended to the end.

Answer (score 1):

A trailer is something that's appended to the end of something else. In this case, it's some extra bytes that are added at the end of the kernel image file. These bytes don't affect the operation of the kernel, but the loader can check for them.

Contrast this with a header, which is something put before something else, like the IP header that goes before the message data in TCP/IP, or the header lines at the beginning of an email.

Comment: It's the reverse of a header, in other words.